# grep a lot of data in the same file

Tags: grep, redhat

I want a command that can match all the below criteria in Red Hat:

```
·number range between 0100xxxx to 0110xxxxx
·And have money over 300
·Status either X or Z
·id contains letter ‘a’
·Error_code starting with 2
```

### number,money,status,error-code,id

```
010018739,13213,X,300,abcde
010523456,343,Z,500,xcvfe
010743576,563,X,201,fgsa
012095654,300,X,400,gcaz
019432343,300,X,402,dewa
011023324,200,X,206,dea
020023433,100,X,303,a
010832134,300,X,200,a
012244242,433,Z,204,ghfsa
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck with?

Comment: IIUC, `awk` is what you're looking for.

Comment: i want to search in this txt file with multiple questions like (number range ,money, Status , id, Error_code)
i have this file and i want to get these output of the lines that meet these criterias

I think grep or awk can solve this issue but i dont know how to use it and which option that needed with grep or awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` only matches text, `awk` is much more flexible and should fit your case better. For instance:

> `awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} $2 > 300 {print;}' < yourfile`

Basically this is saying that `','` is the field separator, and then for every line where the second field (`$2`) is `> 300`, the action (in this case just `print` the whole line, which could even be omitted IIRC) is executed.

You can have conditions as complex as you like, with a syntax that is similar to C. I would suggest reading `man awk` and googling for more complex examples, but you should get the idea.

Comment: yes i used awk  and it works now.
thanks for you info.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
awk -F, '($1>=1000000 && $1<11099999) && $2>300 && ($3 ~ "X" || $3 ~ "Z") && index($5,"a") && index($4,"2")==1' file
```

It doesn't cater for the status being lower-case (but you didn't ask for that), nor does it cater for there being spaces in front of the status or error code (but you didn't ask for that either).